# Getting a NullReferenceException error while rendering a multilist field value

Tags: sitecore-api

I am trying to create a carousel in Sitecore 8.2. I have created a carousel item with the **Image** and **Text** fields and these carousel items are mapped to Multilist.

I am getting a null reference error while rendering the `multilist` items in Visual Studio.

**My View code:**

```
<div id="home-carousel" class="jcarousel-wrapper">
<a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>

<div class="jcarousel carousel-stage">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCarousel" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
<ul class="carousel">
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<li>
<sc:Image Field="Carousel Image" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
<sc:Text Field="Carousel Text" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</ul>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
</div>
```

**My back-end code:**

```
public partial class carousel : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sublayout = Parent as Sublayout;
            var datasource = sublayout.DataSource;
            Item Carousel = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(datasource);
            Item[] item = Carousel.Children.ToArray();
            rptCarousel.DataSource = item;
            rptCarousel.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

[image: Sitecore Content]

[image: Carousel Template]
**UPDATE CODE FROM COMMENT**

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multilistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Select Item"]; 
if (multilistField != null && multilistField.TargetIDs.Any()) 
{
    foreach (ID id in multilistField.TargetIDs)
    {
        Item targetItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items[id];
        Item[] item = targetItem.Children.ToArray();
        rptCarousel.DataSource = item; 
        rptCarousel.DataBind(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: From the code provided, it does not seems that you are reading the MultiList Field. Can you please share how it looks into Sitecore content tree?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I have added Sitecore Content tree references please check..

Comment: one if the carousel items, or one of the images in them, has not been published

Comment: as @HishaamNamooya said, you are doing your code incorrect way, where you are getting all the child items of the datasource item, from the above tree it looks like you have multilist field on your current item and it is not a datasource driven control. is this correct?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya yes I am using Multilist .

Comment: @Adya If you are using a multiList, then your code is not reading from it. You should make sure that all the items have been published and the code datasource should point to sample page. From there you should read the multilist and retrieve the items selected

Comment: @HishaamNamooya I have modified code now its reading values from Multilist . But still i can not see the values in the site .There is no NullReference exception also all items are published in Sitecore .Do I need to make changes in HTML ? How to render multilist Field control in HTML?

Comment: Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multilistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Select Item"];
            if (multilistField != null && multilistField.TargetIDs.Any())
            {
                foreach (ID id in multilistField.TargetIDs)
                {
                    Item targetItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items[id];
                    Item[] item = targetItem.Children.ToArray();
                    rptCarousel.DataSource = item;
                    rptCarousel.DataBind();


                }
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments above, the first issue is that you have a MultiList but the code is not reading from it. Upon the update of the code from the comment section, please see below the updated one.

**Problem**

The updated code you've provided is not correct as it is initializing the array everytime as it is in the loop and also, you are performing a `GetChildren()` on the selected item, which is the carousel item itself.

**Solution**

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multilistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Select Item"];

if (multilistField != null && multilistField.TargetIDs.Any())
{
    var selectedItems = multilistField.GetItems();

    rptCarousel.DataSource = items;

    rptCarousel.DataBind();
}
```

If `GetItems()` method does not exist in your current `Sitecore.Kernel`, which should not be the case, you will need to amend the above code to the one below

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multilistField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Select Item"];

if (multilistField != null && multilistField.TargetIDs.Any())
{
    ArrayList carouselArray = new ArrayList();

    foreach (ID targetId in multilistField.TargetIDs)
    {
        Item carouselItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(targetId);
        if (carouselItem != null)
        {
            carouselArray.Add(carouselItem);
        }
    }

    rptCarousel.DataSource = carouselArray;

    rptCarousel.DataBind();
}
```

Note that you can create an extension for the MultiList field and adds the code that perform the retrieving of the selected items.